# Bitnami database charset and collation issues ,site is created locally

Tags: mysql, collation

I did made site on my localhost using Bitnami application,but when i export my database from *PhpMyAdminm*,and upload to hostting company they told me that they can’t import database because they get the error **charset utf 8 collate utf8_general_ci**,and i should change charset and collation in my *bitnamidatabase.sql* file in notepad,but when i opened i noticed that there is plenty lines of code that contains that so i give up,and i also noticed that in my *phpmyadmin* there is drop-down menu where i can change the charset ,in filed where are the info about database server is this Server charset: **UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4**) for the almost all files in that database collation is **utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci**,what should i do to fix that ,shoud i change type of collation ih the *PhpMyAdmin* or what?

Comment: It is unclear what the expected character set and collation should be. Also, your hosting provider should be able to change charset and collation for your database and connection, they should not expect you to use a centrally defined one.

Comment: The servers charset is very often overwritten by the table definition itself. So if the database has a utf8mb4 it is not a problem that all tables are utf8 instead

Comment: I did change all of tables in database to same collation utf8mb4 unicode 520 ci in phpmyadmin under the operation option ,but one table i cannot change it is utf8 general ci it gives me some kind of error ,and now i upload to them,@shadow they told me that they can't do this and that is not their in charge of that ,and i need to do that manually